# Reading from file at different offsets using Rust

Tags: file, rust

I am working on a project that involves reading different information from a file at different offsets.

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
// ------------------------ SECTORS PER CLUSTER ------------------------

// starts at 13
opened_file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(13)).unwrap();
let aux: &mut [u8] = &mut [0; 1];
let _buf = opened_file.read_exact(aux);

// ------------------------ RESERVED SECTORS ------------------------

// starts at 14
opened_file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(14)).unwrap();
let aux: &mut [u8] = &mut [0; 2];
let _buf = opened_file.read_exact(aux);
```

But as you can see, I need to create a new buffer of the size I want to read every time. I can't specify it directly as a parameter of the function.

I created a struct but I could not make a struct of all the different pieces of data I wanted. For example:

```
struct FileStruct {
    a1: &mut [u8] &mut [0; 1],
    a2: &mut [u8] &mut [0; 2],
}
```

Which are the types that are required for the `read_exact` method to work?

Is there a more effective way to read information from different offsets of a file without having to repeatedly copy-paste these lines of code for every piece of information I want to read from the file? Some sort of function, Cursor, or Vector to easily move around the offset? And a way to write this info into struct fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a struct of owned arrays, then seek and read into the struct.

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, SeekFrom};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
struct FileStruct {
    a1: [u8; 1],
    a2: [u8; 2],
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file_struct: FileStruct = Default::default();
    let mut opened_file = unimplemented!(); // open file somehow
    opened_file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(13))?;
    opened_file.read_exact(&mut file_struct.a1)?;
    opened_file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(14))?;
    opened_file.read_exact(&mut file_struct.a2)?;
    println!("{:?}", file_struct);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f5803f70079598e094594941e4de878)

This is still decently repetitive, so you can make a `seek_read` function to reduce the repetition:

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, SeekFrom};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
struct FileStruct {
    a1: [u8; 1],
    a2: [u8; 2],
}

fn seek_read(mut reader: impl Read + Seek, offset: u64, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
    reader.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset))?;
    reader.read_exact(buf)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file_struct: FileStruct = Default::default();
    let mut opened_file = unimplemented!(); // open file somehow
    seek_read(&mut opened_file, 13, &mut file_struct.a1)?;
    seek_read(&mut opened_file, 14, &mut file_struct.a2)?;
    println!("{:?}", file_struct);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9e35aeeee656526264623ca6152c797)

The repetition can be lowered even more by using a macro:

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, SeekFrom};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
struct FileStruct {
    a1: [u8; 1],
    a2: [u8; 2],
}

macro_rules! read_offsets {
    ($file: ident, $file_struct: ident, []) => {};
    ($file: ident, $file_struct: ident, [$offset: expr => $field: ident $(, $offsets: expr => $fields: ident)*]) => {
        $file.seek(SeekFrom::Start($offset))?;
        $file.read_exact(&mut $file_struct.$field)?;
        read_offsets!($file, $file_struct, [$($offsets => $fields),*]);
    }
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file_struct: FileStruct = Default::default();
    let mut opened_file = unimplemented!(); // open file somehow
    read_offsets!(opened_file, file_struct, [13 => a1, 14 => a2]);
    println!("{:?}", file_struct);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eef5ad50570635435f12ca13f4b1eefe)

Answer (score 1):

This is a complementary answer to Aplet123's: it's not quite clear that you *must* store the bytes as is into a structure, so you can also allocate one buffer (as a fixed-size array) and reuse it with the correctly sized slice e.g.

```
let mut buf = [0u8;16];
opened_file.read_exact(&mut buf[..4])?; // will read 4 bytes
// do thing with the first 4 bytes
opened_file.read_exact(&mut buf[..8])?; // will read 8 bytes this time
// etc...
```

You could also use [the byteorder crate](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.3/byteorder/index.html), which lets you [directly read numbers or sequences of numbers](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.3/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html). It basically just does the unrelying "create stack buffer of the right size; read; decode" for you.

That's especially useful because it looks a lot like "SECTORS PER CLUSTER" should be a u8 and "RESERVED SECTORS" should be a u16. With `byteorder` you can straight `read_16()` or `read_u8()`.

Answer (score 1):

Also building on [Aplet123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127811/reading-from-file-at-different-offsets-using-rust#67128168), the following function `seek_read` doesn't require to know how many bytes to read at compile time, since it uses a Vector instead of a byte slice:

```
// Starting at `offset`, reads the `amount_to_read` from `reader`.
// Returns the bytes as a vector.
fn seek_read(
    reader: &mut (impl Read + Seek),
    offset: u64,
    amount_to_read: usize,
) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    // A buffer filled with as many zeros as we'll read with read_exact
    let mut buf = vec![0; amount_to_read];
    reader.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset))?;
    reader.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    Ok(buf)
}
```

Here are some tests to demonstrate how `seek_read` behaves:

```
use std::io::Cursor;
#[test]
fn seek_read_works() {
    let bytes = b"Hello world!";
    let mut reader = Cursor::new(bytes);

    assert_eq!(seek_read(&mut reader, 0, 2).unwrap(), b"He");
    assert_eq!(seek_read(&mut reader, 1, 4).unwrap(), b"ello");
    assert_eq!(seek_read(&mut reader, 6, 5).unwrap(), b"world");
    assert_eq!(seek_read(&mut reader, 2, 0).unwrap(), b"");
}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "failed to fill whole buffer")]
fn seek_read_beyond_buffer_fails() {
    let mut reader = Cursor::new(b"Hello world!");
    seek_read(&mut reader, 6, 99).unwrap();
}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "failed to fill whole buffer")]
fn start_seek_reading_beyond_buffer_fails() {
    let mut reader = Cursor::new(b"Hello world!");
    seek_read(&mut reader, 99, 1).unwrap();
}
```